# How to implement multi-region pricing whatsapp cloud API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, whatsapp

I am planning to use whatsapp cloud API but I see each country has different rate cards: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/pricing/ If I have application in which registered user can be in USA or UK or India etc and can send messages to users belonging to different countries in that case how to handle pricing implementation on backend?

Is it ok if I calculate the cost based on analytics endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/business-management-api/analytics
this endpoint includes cost as well for each registered phone number. In that case I can easily calculate monthly cost occurring with start and end date in query params. Is there any other solution or can this be improved?

Comment: can you explain what is the use of cost? why it is important to need user/contact wise cost? if user/contact wise is not important then use that analytics endpoint.

Comment: How can I calculate pricing if registered number is in India and messages are sent to USA, UK and other countries?

Comment: That is what i am asking in my first comment, what is the purpose of calculating number wise price? what is the need of that? so according to your requirement we can help you.